# IF error in LISP

Tags: lisp

I am relatively new to Lisp and I was trying to do a linear search on LISP. But I haven't been able to do so. I am always getting an error that says that "IF has too few parameters".

```
(setq a '(8 6 2 3 9 5 1))
(LET (key))
(setq key (read))
(loop
    (if(= (first a) (key)))
        (return t)
        (return NIL)
        (setq a (rest a))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Many problems in your code:

- Globally `setq` an undefined variable
- `(let (key))` alone does nothing. If you want to define a global variable, use `defparameter` or `defvar`.
- You `if` has only a test, and no branches. The special operator `if` takes a condition, a *then* expression and an optional *else* expression: *(if test then [else])*
- If you intended to have your `return` inside the `if`, your linear search would stop at the first comparison, because of (`return NIL`). Indeed, what you would have written would be equivalent to `(return (= (first a) key))` and the `loop` would not even be needed in that case. Maybe you intended to use `return` to return a value from the `if`, but `if` is an expression an already evaluates as a value. `return` exits the loop (there is an implicit `(block NIL ...)` around the `loop`).
- `(setq a (rest a))` is like `(pop a)` and would indeed be the right thing to do if you did not already returned from `loop` at this point.
- Just to be sure, be aware that `=` is for comparing *numbers*.

The beginning of your code can be written as:

```
(let ((a '(8 6 2 3 9 5 1))
      (key (read)))
  (linear-search key a)
```

Then, how you perform `linear-search` depends on what you want to learn. There are built-in for this (`find`, `member`). You can also use `some` with a predicate. `Loop` has a `thereis` clause. You can even try with `reduce` or `map` with a `return-from`. If you want to learn `do` or `tagbody`, you will have an occasion to use `(pop a)`.